# how to pass the param in $.ajax to be filtered in json?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
 var type = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'path/to/example.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {type: "type"} //not working?
          ......

    {
```

Json

```
  "name": "Jh",
  "type": "zoologist, hobbyist"
},
```

HTML

```
   <div class="filter">
          <a href="?type=all" id="all">View All</a>
          <a href="?type=zoologist" id="zoologist">Zoologist</a>
          <a href="?type=hobbyist" id="hobbyist">Hobbyist</a>
          <a href="?type=judge" id="judge">Judge</a>
      </div>
```

Not familiar with $.ajax and frustrated for a quite long while, trying to pass the param to filter by type in json.

Filter Link will be clicked on and then will get attribute of id. Then want to pass this id to data: {type: type}.

Wanted to retrieve details of the same type filtered

Not understand why it is not doing anything. Or it is not possible to filter by type in json?

Comment: Not clear, what you want to filter.

Comment: @dfsq - sorry. I wanted to filter out by type in json and then retrieve all details in json with certain type

Comment: "filter" at `php` or  returned `js`  ? Can include `html` at OP ?

Comment: @guest271314 - filter via $.ajax not sure if it is even possible or not. JS please.

Comment: Passing data to a JSON file won't do anything. That's essentially what you're doing right now. No matter what data you pass, a JSON file will have no idea what to do with it. You'll have to either change your URL to a PHP file that can filter the JSON for you or grab the JSON as a whole and then filter it via Javascript.

Comment: Also, you are not passing the var `type` into your data object. You are just passing the string "type". You will need to change it to `{type: type}`. Note: this will not fix your problem, but this is wrong regardless.

Comment: Is `json` _complete_ `json` file ? What is expected return value from`json` if `id="zoologist"` clicked ? `"zoologist, hobbyist"` ? if `id="hobbist"` clicked ? , `"zoologist, hobbyist"` ?

Comment: Lastly, use Chrome Dev tools (or Firefox/IE tools) to check what data is being passed in each AJAX call. http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console--net-28167

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it would be better to filter the data before sending it back to the client, but according to the comments you didn't use/want any server side code.

So, just using js, you could return the whole data-set and filter it:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'path/to/example.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('success, filtering response...');

        //Filter the returned json by "filter"            
        var filteredJson = $(response).filter(function (i,n) { 
            return n.type === $('#someId').attr('id'); 
        });

        //... more code
    }
 });
```